# Blender 2.8+ Editing Spiral Curves

Tags: edit-mode, bezier-curves

I've looked everywhere looked through every menu, and for the life of me I can't find the spirals menu in blender 2.8. I can't add turns or steps to my spiral curve, can anyone tell me how to bring up the menu? otherwise it's no different than adding a circle curve.

Comment: You need to do it as soon as you've created your curve, in the Operator box (bottom left of your 3D view), it won't be available anymore if you move your curve or select another object

Comment: Thank you so much! I was completely missing that menu because I was moving the curve before trying to edit it!