# Editing Spiral Curves 2.92

Tags: objects, shortcut, operator

Is there still no way to edit the turns of a spiral form after creating it?

([Blender 2.8+ Editing Spiral Curves](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199259/blender-2-8-editing-spiral-curves))

I tried using F9 (Adjust Last Operation) but I just get a notification that says Toggle Edit Mode in both Object and Edit Mode, without seeing the Operator Menu that comes up when I immediately add an object. I constantly want to go back to the operator menu to change just one thing after creating an object but it doesn't seem you can?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, whenever you do something AFTER the dialog is gone, you never get this dialog again. This happens by the way with all of these „settings“ dialogs whenever you create something (curve, mesh, whatever).